# Groovy: how to get the value of a ?private? closure variable

Tags: groovy, scope, closures, private

I have a closure thats working great, but sometimes I would like to get the final value of a temporary variable I define in the closure.  Example:

```
def someClosure = {Number input->
  def howDoIGetThis = input + 4
  return 2 * input
}

def normalWay = someClosure(2)
assert normalWay == 4

def myFantasy = someClosure(2).howDoIGetThis
assert myFantasy == 6
```

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the state in the closure's owner or delegate.

```
def howDoIGetThis
def someClosure = {Number input ->
    howDoIGetThis = input + 4
    return input * 2
}

def normalWay = someClosure(2)
assert normalWay == 4

someClosure(2)
def myFantasy = howDoIGetThis
assert myFantasy == 6
```

If you want to control what object the state goes into, you can override the closure's delegate.  For example:

```
def closureState = [:]
def someClosure = {Number input ->
    delegate.howDoIGetThis = input + 4
    return input * 2
}
someClosure.delegate = closureState

def normalWay = someClosure(2)
assert normalWay == 4

someClosure(2)
def myFantasy = closureState.howDoIGetThis
assert myFantasy == 6
```

Comment: +1 nice alternatives :-) bit side-effecty for my liking though ;-)

Comment: super groovy... is the side effect just that anything made `def howDoIGetThis` in the answer scope will be set to 6 or whatever when you `def normalWay = someClosure(2)`? (in the second example)

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no way of getting the variable, as the closure just returns a single result (so `somclosure(2).howDoIGetThis` can't work), and there's no way to get a handle on the closure instance after it has been run...

The best I can think of, is to return multiple values from the Closure like so:

```
def someClosure = {Number input->
  def howDoIGetThis = input + 4
  [ 2 * input, howDoIGetThis ]
}

def (normalWay, myFantasy) = someClosure(2)

assert normalWay == 4
assert myFantasy == 6
```